# Resend Opt-in email to unsubscribed member using MailChimp API V3.0

Tags: email, mailchimp, confirmation, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I have a situation where I would like to programmatically (re)send a confirmation (opt-in link) email to a member who has unsubscribed.

I know I cannot directly re-subscribe them, but I was hoping there would be a means of at least sending a confirmation email.

**Is it possible to trigger the confirmation email for an unsubscribed member in vs 3.0 of the API?**

I know I can resend it from the Web UI but I'd really like to accomplish it via an API request when a user who has previously unsubscribed performs some action on the website indicating they'd like to be added again.

Deleting and Adding the member is a last resort, but I would prefer to keep the original account (and its data) in place.

Comment: According to this: "Contacts who unsubscribe themselves cannot be deleted." http://kb.mailchimp.com/lists/manage-contacts/resubscribe-a-contact

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Re-sending an opt-in email for someone who is still in a `pending` state isn't supported AFAIK, but once the user is unsubscribed, I think if you set them back to `pending` it will resend the email.

Alternately, I've not found deleting and resubscribing to cause much data loss (if any) so you might try that out too, if the above doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks a million! The "pending" status does trigger the confirmation email to go out to a previously unsubscribed member.